# How can I set the onTouchListener directly on the xml layout file using data binding?

Tags: android, android-databinding

I have been successful with adding `onClick` listeners directly

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="@{action::onItemClicked}" />
```

and `onRefreshListener` listeners as well

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:onRefreshListener="@{action::onRefresh}">
```

but I cannot understand why I am not able to do the following

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:onTouchListener="@{action::onItemTouched}" />
```

It shows the following error:

> Listener class android.view.View.OnTouchListener with method onTouch did not match signature of any method action::onItemTouched

And another error if I use `android:` instead of `app:` or `onTouch` instead of `onTouchListener`.

Yet the method signature of `onItemTouched` is as defined in the `View.java` source file:

```
public void onItemTouched(View v, MotionEvent event) {

    // no dice

}
```

As far as I can see, `TextView` is a `View` and as such it should have worked: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/a175a5b/core/java/android/view/View.java#14494

So what am I doing wrong, why won't this work? Should it be a different attribute name?

And please no `@BindingAdapter` or similar suggestions, I already know how to do it that way. My objective is to keep the model clutter free and attach the methods directly on the views as I did for clicks and swipe refresh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working, the only problem was the method was `void`, but the `onTouch` signature requires a `boolean` return. In the end this is how it should be:

Layout file sample

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onTouch="@{action::onItemTouched}" />
```

or

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onTouchListener="@{action::onItemTouched}" />
```

Action class method

```
public boolean onItemTouched(View v, MotionEvent event) {

    // now it works, do your magic
    return true; // or return false, depending on what you want to do

}
```

Only worry now is Android Studio complains that `android:onTouch` is an unknown attribute, I hope it won't turn non-public for some odd reason in the future. For that reason I will be using the following method in the layout just to get rid of the warning message

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:onTouch="@{action::onItemTouched}" />
 // app:onTouchListener works as well
```